# Overlapping tooltip in Extjs Grid

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have an issue that I’ve been trying to resolve.  I’m very new to Sencha ExtJS. I’ve included image links to assist my explanation.

I have a Tooltip  that displays “Double-click to Configure” when you move your MouseOver the header of a table which works fine.

Shown here: http://img227.imagevenue.com/img.php?image=952843717_Header_122_41lo.jpg

Also
I have a Tooltip  that displays “Show Available Options” when you move your MouseOver the gear icon.

The problem is that the gear icon is within the header so when you mouseover the gear icon, the header tooltip also displays displays. Shown here
http://img157.imagevenue.com/img.php?image=952937141_Config_122_421lo.jpg

I really don’t know how EXTJS renders it’s grid but is there a way for me to place the gear icon outside of the header or not display the “Double-click to Configure” Tooltip when a user mouseovers the gear icon?

I’m Not sure where to look in the code I have a file uiconstant.js that creates all the UI constants in a Static class

```
UIElements:
{
    SIMULATION_GRID: 'simulationgrid',
    REPORT_SCHEDULER: 'reportscheduler',
    BLENDED_BENCHMARK: 'blendedBenchmark',
    BLENDED_BENCHMARK_GROUPINGS: 'blendedBenchmark_groupings',
    DEFAULT_CONTAINER_LABEL: 'Click to configure container',
    EDIT_CONFIGURE_CONTAINER_LABEL: 'Click to edit configuration',
    DO_NOT_REQUEST_CONTENT_LABEL: 'Automatic calculation off for this dashboard.',
    NO_RECORDS_FOUND: '<div class="no-records-found">No records found</div>',
    CONTAINER_PANEL: 'containerPanel',
    DoubleClickToConfigure: 'Double-click to Configure'
}
```

I also have a ContainerPanel.js File that Represents the custom panel for the container.
Not sure if I am looking in the correct files to make this change or update the grid

```
    Ext.create('Ext.tip.ToolTip', {
        target: header,
        html: UiConstant.UIElements.DoubleClickToConfigure

    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tooltip is supported for tools so you can configure the gear with a tooltip text. Now, header does not directly support tooltips - you handle it above by creating one and setting its header.

Let's try a bit different approach: tooltip on gear tool is de facto *quicktip* - only one instance of quicktip exists at a time.

To create quicktip for the header do this:

```
panel.getHeader().getEl().set({'data-qtip':'Your text here'});
```

Note: There shall always be an area around the gear tool where the tooltip changes - not sure if it is acceptable for your use case. Nevertheless, two tips shall not appear.

Comment: One more thing Where .js file should I create this in? Also I need to define Panel first correct?

Comment: The same place where you now call `Ext.create('Ext.tip.ToolTip'...` is fine. There you already have reference to the header.